# Placing focus on JTextArea when JFrame starts

Tags: java, swing

I'm aware this is something that has been asked and I've used some of the solutions/examples provided in the forum but they seem to be unable to work for me.

Essentially I have JInternalFrames which contain JTextAreas and I would like it it that when the JInternalFrame is visible focus i.e. the cursor is placed on the JTextArea as opposed to the user having to manually place the cursor by clicking on the JTextArea.

Below are my attempted solutions:

Solution 1:

```
textAreaUName.requestFocus(true);
```

Solution 2:

```
textAreaUName.requestFocus(true);
textAreaUName.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Apologies once again if you have seen the question being asked severally.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Please see how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are likely to get better help if you post one for us to test.

Comment: Where have you written those statements, since `requestFocusInWindow()` should be called on the visible `Component`. And restrain yourself from using `requestFocus()` since the outcome of this function is platform dependent.

Comment: Try to wrap the solution 2 in SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: requestFocusInWindow() works for me.  Try placing the call in WindowListener.windowOpened()

Answer (score 1):

This will set the focus on a JComponent which is not null and focusable.

```
public final void requestFocus(final JComponent component)
{
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!component.isFocusOwner()) {
                component.requestFocusInWindow();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    if(component!=null&&component.isFocusable())
    {
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andie, thanks for the reply but I attempted all three solutions and none worked.